# Azure Data Flow Aggregate transformation not showing columns in groupby dropdown

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

In the following [Azure Data Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/concepts-data-flow-overview), the `Employee` source is an `employee.csv` file. And I need to groupby `DEPARTMENT_ID` of employee.csv. But the `BroupBy` dropdown (shown below) is not showing any columns to choose from. However, the source's `Preview Data` button does show the data from the employee.csv file.

**Question**: Why the `BroupBy` dropdown not showing any column, and can we fix the issue?

**Data Flow**:

[image]

**Snapshot of Preview data of Source: Employee**

[image]

Comment: In the Source transformation, click on the Projection tab. Make sure that the schema from the file is imported into the data flow. Otherwise, without that projection, data flow does not know about the underlying file schema, so it cannot show the columns in the transformation metadata.

Comment: @MarkKromerMSFT Thank you for sharing your knowledge - it helped. +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cross check your dataset schema in Dataset settings, in Source Projection and make sure that schema is imported.

In your Dataset, make sure you have check marked **First row as header** option under **Connection Tab**. This will make first row as Column names when dataset is .csv file.

[image]

Then, under **Schema Tab**, follow **Import Schema -> From connection/store.** This will show your first row as column names. Refer below image.

[image]

Now, in your Data flow, under Source Projection settings, it must be showing the column names. If not, follow **Projection -> Import projection** to import the schema from dataset settings. Follow below image.

[image]

Finally, after all these settings, you will be able to see column names under Aggregate settings as shown below.

[image]